# looking for dropdown component for angular2

Tags: angular, components

I'm looking for a dropdown select component for Angular2 without dependencies other than Angular2 itself.
all the component that I found require jquery or I have to use it without dependencies other than Angular2 itself

Comment: Not sure if it uses other library but you can have a look at it:
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Comment: Does it just have to be a simple dropdown that handles objects and displays a single text field for select. Or do you need functionality like custom images in the dropdown, checkboxes...

Comment: You can use Angular Material: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ - technically it's another dependency but it's still part of the Angular "family"

Comment: I found ng2-select  https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/

Comment: @FilipLauc the seconde choise I need custom images,

Answer (score 2):

Creating a custom dropdown isn't that big a deal. Plus it's as 'light-weight' as you can get. All you need to do is:

1. Create a list of elements out of the passed data
2. Make the list visible on click and hide it again when a list element is selected
3. Emit the data when an element is selected

This is basically everything you need:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-select',
      template: `
          <div class="selected" (click)="openClose()">
              <div class="when-selected" *ngIf="selected">
                  <span>{{selected.title}}</span>
                  <img [src]="selected.img" />
              </div>
              <div class="placeholder" *ngIf="!selected">
                  This is shown when nothing is selected
              </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="select" [hidden]="closed">
              <li *ngFor="let o of options" (click)="select(o)">
                  <span>{{o.title}}</span>
                  <img [src]="o.img" />
              </li>
          </ul>
          `
      })

      export class CustomSelect {
          @Input() options: any;

          @Input() selected: any;
          @Output() selectedChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

          closed: boolean = true;

          select(option: any): void {
              this.selected = option;
              this.selectedChange.emit(option);
              this.openClose();
          }

          openClose(): void {
              this.closed = !this.closed;
          }
      }
```

And you use it like this:

```
<custom-select [(selected)]="myItem" [options]="allOptions"></custom-select>
```

Here is the entire [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R4Q6vU8Eir8wF4G1u26u?p=preview)

Now you only need to style it and maybe change the element structure to something that fits you.

Comment: thank's Filip, it's interesting. I already use ng2-select I'm satisfied about the rendering but I don't know how to get the element that I select. Maybe I have to set the value selected in a hidden input.

Comment: What do you mean? The selected element is stored in the myItem property of the parent component. Can you give me an example of how you want to use it?

Comment: In reality you need much more, like styling. But this answer is a great base that I could extend in 1-2 hours into a working multi level custom select.